# Error in viewing document with onclick of document URL link

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

- I am trying to open and view a document in react app with the URL link
- On clicking the URL link, showing the same error constantly in the console

  > Blocked script execution in '' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.
- Still, the document is rendered in UI
- I researched for the error and displayed result related to deployment issues
- Struck with the idea of which part of the App hitting error
- can you guys help me to resolve the issue with your suggestions
- The entire code is available in the stackbiltz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8dv5yl?file=index.js
  -providing the code snippet below:

App.js

```
export function App(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      { sportsProfile(user) }
    </div>
  );
}
```

sportsProfile.js

```
Java link: <a href="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1axZ-C9TqnNJy_iFQBGQ5G1ZzT54enCGWGHHAV3BcVWQ/edit">https://docs.google.com/document/d/1axZ-C9TqnNJy_iFQBGQ5G1ZzT54enCGWGHHAV3BcVWQ/edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your app runs in a Iframe at the Stackblitz website.

The google document does't allow other website which includes itself in a Iframe. So the docs.google.com rejects your request or blocks your execution of javascript code in Google's page, because your page is in a Iframe at the Stackblitz view.

Run your code in your local that would be fine if there wasn't contained by any Iframe, or you can change your link to other urls that allow you include it in a Iframe.

It protects the user from XSS, more information about Iframe, please see https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Comment: @Simon.Lay...Thanks for your reply...I runned in local machine with node.js server. Still, I am experiencing the same error...can you able to provide your suggestion whether we need to any properties in the response headers for non-blocking execution of URL

Comment: @tamilcool So you are using Iframe to contain other website? Ah, as your error info, you can set your Iframe "sandbox" to be "allow-scripts", here is an example at last of  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp.  Btw, other websites are able to decide whether you can contain it in your Iframe, that is easy to do that.

Comment: @Simon.Lay...Thanks for your reply...I'll modify and execute the code with your suggestions and let you know about the output

Comment: @Simon.Lay...After setting allow-scripts and modals permission, showing error as "Blocked iframe with origin "null" from accesing cross-origin frame".....I am planning to use <a> tag providing link for the document to get viewed.....can you let me know whether this can be achieved with <a> tag

Comment: @tamilcool No, it can't achieved with <a> tag. This is a cross-origin problem that we can't solve it, only Google can sets which domain is the same origin.

Comment: @tamilcool Your issue is getting complex, it is a question that how to load Google   Document in your website by Iframe. That's actually hardest to solve it or can't solve it.

Comment: Anyway, that's all my answer, if you want to chat with me, please leave your twitter, Im glad to chat with you.

Comment: @Simon.Lay...Thanks for your reply...that could be my question...I'll try to make with other alternative and let you know about the results